# upload a file with PHP

Tags: php, upload, photo

HTML FORM

```
<form name="nv" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Photo:</td>
<td><input name="photo" type="file" size="58"></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><input name="res" type="reset" value="reset"></td>
<td><input name="sub" type="submit" value="s'enregistrer"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

PHP

```
$file_result = "";
if($_FILES["photo"]["error"]>0){

    $file_result =" il y a un error lors de la telechargement de la photo, error : <br />". $_FILES["photo"]["error"];

    }else{

        $path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EasyPHP-5.3.9\\www\\2011pr\photos\\";

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["name"],$path);

        $file_result = $_FILES["photo"]["name"] . "  est bien telecharge a dans le serveur";
        }

    echo " <br /> ". $file_result." <br /> ";
```

it gives me this error:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: The
>   second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\2011pr\nouveau.php on line 129
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to
>   move 'C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\tmp\phpF33.tmp' to
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\2011pr\photos\' in
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\2011pr\nouveau.php on line
>   129

Comment: Just read error message ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of `move_uploaded_file()` requires a file path, not a folder path. Therefore, you need to change

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["name"],$path);
```

to

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],$path.$yourNewFilename);
```

Also, `$_FILES["photo"]["name"]` is this file name like `picture.jpg`. `$_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"]` is the temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

`move_uploaded_file()` requires a destination FILENAME, you're just providing a path. e.g.

```
move_uploaded_file($foo, '/some/directory/'); // illegal
move_uploaded_file($foo, '/some/directory/kittens.jpg'); // valid - specifying a filename.
```

In other words, RTFError.. PHP **TOLD** you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your warning:

> The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\2011pr\nouveau.php on line
>   129

In effect try a different directory. Not a good idea to be writing code in your Program Files anyway. Make a directory in your Documents folder or under your username folder instead.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, the second parameter of `move_uploaded_file()` should be the full path to the file itself - *including* the new filename.

See here https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file